is Goku SSJ1 or SSJ2 when he fights the Tamagami?
In Dragon Ball Daima, the first time Goku transforms into SSJ1 after being turned into a kid, he says he didnt know if he could do it. Then he fights with the Tamagami and we see sparks of electricity which first appeared in the SSJ2 transformation, but which later were used ocasionally in SSJ1 transformations.
So I was wondering, is Goku SSJ1 or SSJ2 when he fights the Tamagami? can he turns SSJ2 after being turned into a kid?

"...which later were used occasionally in SSJ1 transformations...", for example?
